# Pass generic list into <include>

Tags: android, android-databinding

Have two complex layouts and one is included into another.
Trying to pass list of some custom objects into included layout, but build fails with following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find type element for List
file:D:\myproject-android\core\src\main\res\layout\view_header.xml
loc:101:27 - 101:42
****\ data binding error ****
```

**view_header.xml:**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.catalogz.app.ui.categories.ItemViewModel" />
    </data>
    <FrameLayout>
       <include layout="@layout/include_title_view" bind:items="@{vm.items}/>
    </FrameLayout>
   ...
</layout>
```

**include_title_view.xml:**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <import type="com.catalogz.app.utils.Strings" />
        <import type="com.catalogz.app.app.entities.Item" />
        <import type="java.util.List"/>
        <variable
            name="items"
            type="List&lt;Item&gt;" /> <!-- generic List<Item> -->
    </data>
    <TextView android:text="@{Strings.convert(items)}"/>
</layout>
```

It's possible to move this problem from **view_header.xml** to **include_title_view.xml** by removing generic definition `&lt;Item&gt;` but then it appears in the `Strings.convert(items)` call as methods expects a list of `Item` and layout passes `List<Object>` as I understand:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find method convert(java.util.List) in class com.catalogz.app.utils.Strings
file:D:\myproject-android\core\src\main\res\layout\include_title_view.xml
loc:51:32 - 51:61
****\ data binding error ****
```

Comment: Have you found an answer? I am in the same situation. Why it gives that error?

Comment: It gives me an error itself in IDE, Cannot resolve symbol `Map<String, Friend>` in my case

Comment: So, I just decided to use raw types. It's not that safe but at least works.

Comment: Regarding IDE, it can fakely show an error but the code itself be compilable. Just in case... :)

Comment: Last one, ensure you use escaped version of < &lt; and > &gt;

Comment: Yes It worked. But I am seriously getting tough time with Maps. Documentation says it works. But sometimes not!

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problems, but I found an alternative for setting the value inside the included layout. I know it is not a good practice, at least it is the work around for the setting variable for the include layout with data binding.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.catalogz.app.ui.categories.ItemViewModel" />
    </data>
    <FrameLayout>
       <include 
    android:id="@+id/part1"
    layout="@layout/include_title_view" />
    </FrameLayout>
   ...
</layout>
```

In Activity class

```
ActivityMainBinding.part1.setItems(myItems);
```

Hope this can be helpful.

Comment: that's an interesting option, thanks. It kinda giving up an advantage of databinding itself but, on the other hand, it's safe and reliable. I decided to be a bit risky and just removed generic and casting objects to required type.