# Error when importing List type into xml file using Android Data binding

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-databinding

When I try to import the **List class** type into an **xml file** using Android Data Binding I receive the following error

```
Error: cannot find type element for List.
```

This error is really frustrating because I followed [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) documentation and it doesn't appear to be correct. Although there are quite a lot of data binding tutorials online, I can't manage to find one which covers this particular issue.

The data section in my **xml file** looks as follows:

```
<data>

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <import type="java.util.List" />

    <import type="com.example.app.Book" />

    <variable
        name="books"
        type="List&lt;Book&gt;" />

</data>

List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
mBinding.setBooks(books);
```

Has anyone managed to solve this issue? I would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: Please post how you set your `List` to the binding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293644/pass-generic-list-into-include

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have edited the question to include the code that binds the list.

Comment: I am having the same error but for Map

Comment: I am really stuck at this issue. If you find anything please let me know.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I met the problem just now,

```
Error:(34, 26) cannot find type element for List
```

and solved it by replacing

```
<data>
    <import type="java.util.List"/>
    <variable
        name="list"
        type="List&lt;String&gt;"/>
</data>
```

with

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="list"
        type="java.util.List&lt;String&gt;"/>
</data>
```

Hope this can help you!

---

Besides, try to reference type with full qualified  class name instead of short class name. Like

```
type="java.util.List&lt;com.example.app.Book&gt;"
```

because in my case, I found the *import* tag does not make any sense.

Comment: For me it worked like this `type="java.util.List&lt;com.example.app.Book>"` for some weird reason, the second `>` didn't need to be escaped.

Comment: @PanosGr You only need to escape the less-than sign in XML, not greater-than